# dropdownlist no postback

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu, postback

How can I make a dropdownlist with no postback - I have a dropdownlist which has code in `selectedindexchanged`

Basically for every `indexchanged` the code will connect to sql and get values then populate textboxes with values.

Here is my code

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSalesOrg" runat="server" Style="width: 200px;"  
  AutoPostBack="true" />
```

I want that the `selectedindexchange` should get hit, but it should NOT cause a full postback. If I set the `AutoPostBack` to false, then it won't hit `selectedindexchange` at all

Comment: not sure i get the question but, shouldnt AutoPostBack="false" be enough ?

Comment: @futile Look at last line of question - OP wants postbacks from one side, but don't wants them from other side.

Comment: @VMAtm so what i understand is, the postback will depend on the selected index value ?

Comment: @futile I think that this is already implemented, and spy just don't need full postback.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - what im trying to say is - I want to trigger my indexchanged event without postback.. hope i sound clearly now..thanks...

Answer (score 2):

You must choose - do you want postback or not. You can't set `AutoPostBack="true"` and after that stop the post backs.

If you just don't need full postback - use [UpdatePanel](http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/updatepanel-control/) for partial page update.

Answer (score 1):

I dont get you question,  do you want avoid the postback and also have the funcionality of vb/C# on every indexchanged?

Then your solution were AJAX all this time.
At this time I supose you have more knowledge about this.

But only for the register.

When you write something in the codebehing of ASP in response to an event, there you MUST be a postback (or partial postback) to achieve that code.

If you stop the postback  abiously (as you said) these code is not achieved.

If you want to avoid the postback and also get some databind functionality (or any server side functionality) then you can disable the postback, handle the event in javascript, and call some AJAX function to make the databind.

key words for your next google search: ajax, dropdownlist,asp

Good luck to the next guy who has this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `AutoPostBack` property of the list to true.

Also, if you're populating the contents of the drop down list from the code behind (getting the contents of the list from a database, for example) - make sure you're not re-binding the data in every postback.

Sometimes people are caught out by binding the drop-down in the page load event without putting it in an If Not IsPostBack. This will cause the event not to fire.

The same is also true of repeaters and ItemCommand events.

Comment: `AutoPostBack` is already set to postback. OP wants to **stop** postbacks.